# beautiful soup get_text() works on jupyter notebook and from cmd but not in Pycharm/Heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

I'm running a python web app using Dash (Flask) on Heroku and am using bs4 for web scraping. I have the following code which uses 'get_text()' to create a string from part of a soup and then search within the soup for specific keywords. I have executed the following code on jupyter notebooks and from the command line with a .py file and it works both times, but when I run it in Pycharm or deploy it to Heroku I get an error.

I have checked that the string I am searching for is located in the soup. The error is with the get_text() function, in notebooks/cmd it produces an output string as supposed to, but in Pycharm/Heroku it produces no output (nothing is printed when I go print(individual_script) after that line as opposed to before, where it produces the appropriate soup object.

```
def extractDataFromGraph(soup, chart_id):
    scripts = soup.select('script[type="text/javascript"]')
    for individual_script in scripts:
        individual_script = individual_script.get_text(strip=True)
        if chart_id in individual_script:
            x_text = re.search('categories: \[([^\]]+)\]', individual_script).group(1)
            y_text = re.search('data: \[([0-9, ]+)]', individual_script).group(1)
            x_values = x_text.replace('"', '').split(",")
            y_values = y_text.split(",")
    return (x_values, y_values)
```

And get the following error in Pycharm:

```
  File "C:/Users/Jason Collis/Documents/Python Scripts/coronavirus-visualisations/get_data.py", line 53, in extractDataFromGraph
    return (x_values, y_values)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x_values' referenced before assignment
```

Could it be due to my version of python or some weird incompatability with bs4? I'm running 3.6 on cmd and 3.8 on Pycharm.

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: If the `for` loop or the `if` statement inside never run, `x_values` will not get set.

Comment: Yes, this is the problem. It is not running because 'invididual script' is completely blank after I run get_text() on it, whereas when I run it in jupyter notebooks it returns a valid string.